# Raspberry pi wlan0 appears but not enable to enter internet

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, networking, wifi

I have raspberry pi2 and I want to connect wifi with adding wifi adaptor to my raspberry pi. So I did some adjustments :

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "VINNWiFi_C54D"
    wpa-psk "80052712"
```

And also:

> ifconfig

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:e7:16:00:f7:e9
          inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::62a0:73ef:9526:ab50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:367 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:29695 (28.9 KiB)  TX bytes:12226 (11.9 KiB)
```

I realized it shows the internet connection is okay. But when I try to enter a website(ex:www.google.com), it says "The site can't be reached". So I can not enter any website. Thank you..

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. What kind of wireless card are you using? 2. Can you ping your gateway (type: "route" to show the gateway) 3. Can you ping google.com?